# Is there any way to accept type as an parameter for a static method in Java in the following way?

Tags: java, class, oop, templates

My main aim is to achieve the following syntax while calling the static method by **any** means.

```
MyClass.staticMethod<Type>();
```

This is what I have achieved so far,

```
static <T> void MyClass()
{
/* Function Body */
}
```

Comment: And what will that syntax accomplish?

Comment: A specific form of syntax I am looking for...

Comment: That's not how SO works. If you want your question to survive, you'll have to explain yourself better. You can't come waltzing in here and say "I want this syntax, but I won't explain why". That's not a programming question. The Java syntax is well defined, your problem isn't. You can help with the latter one, by making sure this isn't an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm just trying to omit the `new` keyword.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? See, your question has nothing to do with syntax. Probably nothing to do with the `new` keyword either. You can still salvage this question by editing it and actually asking your **real** question. Not "how can I get arbitrary syntax because I'm trying to avoid `new` for some unknown reason".

Comment: @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow *"I'm just trying to omit the `new` keyword"* What does that mean? You don't seem to be trying to use `new` in the first place, so what are you trying to omit it from?

Comment: Omit it from the syntax of Object creation

Comment: So you're trying to write a `static` method for the caller to use, so the `new` operator is in the `static` method and the caller doesn't need to use `new`? E.g. like how all the new Java Time classes do it, where you call e.g. `LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 10)` instead of `new LocalDate(2020, 3, 10)`? If that is what you mean, then **edit** the question and say so, because that is certainly not how the question currently reads. You should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that but for generic types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a generic class like

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    public MyClass() {
    }
}
```

which is normally instantiated using `new`

```
new MyClass<Type>()
```

but you don't want the caller to use `new`, you want a `static` method to do that, then do it like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    public static <T> MyClass<T> newInstance() {
        return new MyClass<T>();
    }
    private MyClass() {
    }
}
```

The caller can now do:

```
MyClass.<Type>newInstance()
```

though the `Type` can generally be *inferred*:

```
MyClass<Type> myObj = MyClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: So myClass.newInstance<int> isn't possible, eg. when i want to directly pass it to an function?

Comment: @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow No, the **Java syntax** is `MyClass.<Integer>newInstance()`, and you cannot use a primitive type like `int` as a type argument. I though we already covered what the Java syntax allows, many times. Besides, the `<Integer>` part can usually be omitted, because the compiler can *infer* it, even when used as a method parameter.

Comment: Eg. anotherFunction(MyClass.newInstance<int>(1,2,3))

Comment: Some other way to accept type as a parameter within `<>` using some other concept altogether

Comment: @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow Already answered! If you want type argument within `<>`, then it goes *before* the method name. End of story!

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
MyClass.<Type>staticMethod();
```

```
static <T> void staticMethod() {
    // Function Body
}
```

You can write that, but the method won't know what `T` is because of type-erasure.

If the method needs to know `T`, then you need

```
MyClass.staticMethod(Type.class);
```

```
static <T> void staticMethod(Class<T> clazz) {
    // Function Body
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to put that `Type` ahead?

Comment: @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow "Ahead"? Of what? --- Only way for the method to *know* anything about `T`, is for it to receive a parameter. Since you haven't shown why you need `T`, it is difficult to say if there are other means that would work for you.

Comment: I mean just as I had mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow And I showed you what the Java syntax allows. So: *No!*

Comment: Some alternative way...I am ready to use some other concept altogether, just to achieve that syntax...

Comment: @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow *"just to achieve that syntax"* You cannot make up your own syntax in Java. Java doesn't support that syntax, so I'll repeat: The answer to your question is: ***No!*** --- You can put the `<Type>` *before* the method name, but the method won't know what `T` is at runtime, so what's the point?

Comment: @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow Any luck with what? --- *"I have actually done it"* No idea what you have already done, since you haven't shown us what you've done. The code in your question certainly doesn't compile, so that cannot be it. **Edit** the question and show us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want further help. Until then, the answer remains: ***No***, the Java syntax doesn't allow what you wrote in the question, however this answer shows you what you *can* do, so you can adjust your needs to fit it.